# How do large sites like StackOverflow handle their access logs?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic, logging, apache-log-files

I'm wondering how large sites like StackOverflow handle their access logs. A write to the disk on every request seems a little bit uneconomical, but is Google Analytics that reliable to use it as your only information resource?

Comment: You can set up Apache to log to a database. I imagine IIS is the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is much information that web server logs contain which will never be available to Google Analytics, two things I can think of:

- Errors like 404, etc.
- Access on media files, like pictures, etc. (including external websites linking to your images)
- IP addresses, although an answer to another question pointed out that it can be set as a user variable
- Full length referral URLs, for example Google sends links from product search, web search, etc. each search has keywords but Google Analytics does not display the other variables like `&source=products`, etc.

Must be more stuff I just can't think of right now.

And there are also the error logs; must be important for a website to run smoothly, in my opinion. Not something you would ignore.

Comment: Thats right, but how do they store their logs? File or database as suggested by Lèse majesté seems to heavy to me.

Comment: Actually, when you gzip this kind of repetitive data ... it compresses really well. So I imagine you can just store it as compressed text files and remove them after a while ... just your basic rotation.

Answer (score 2):

On a *nix system you could use [syslog-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng) to store log messages on a dedicated log server for your load-balanced cluster(s) and then use a log analysis solution like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) to keep tabs on things - as for what the StackExchange sites actually run, may be a good question for [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Has anyone asked yet what stack exchange uses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really look at these logs and end up deleting them on a monthly basis.  I only look at them for trouble shooting.  As for as monitoring application use Google Analytics, CrazyEgg and others do a great job.

Before such services existed these logs were very valuable.  Now, they are good developer tools, but I don't know of any of my colleagues or friends that actively archive these logs or parse them for data.